# led circuit - a challenge of designing a circuit with 192 LEDs in

Tags: led, resistors, voltage-measurement, led-driver, led-matrix

I have been faced with a challenge of designing the circuitry for an LED light.  This light will have 96 LEDs in Cyan with a max Vf of 3.7V and another 96 LEDs in red with a Vf of 2.6V.  There is to be a Vs of 24V.
One challenge is to get 100% of power going through 1 colour, then an option of switching to 100% to the other colour, and a third option of 50% power going through both colours at once (all 192 LEDs).
I have only got a short time to try to do this and Im struggling due to my inexperience.
I have started working on the calculation of the resistors needed for the Cyan and worked out that 6x3.7=22.2v so thats fine within the 24v limit.
I see that 6 LEDs in series of 16 rows will work out as 96 so thats one colour being seen to, making it 24v-(3.7v x 6)=1.8v.
I believe the current through the whole circuit for the Vs of 24V is going to be 340mA so I make that 1.8/0.34=5.3ohm per resistor.
(I don't remember if I should split the current value between the 16 rows to get this calculation correct (perhaps someone can shed some light on this) as that makes the power dissipated across each resistor P=i^2 x R(making it 0.34^2 x 5.3=0.62W, which may be right?).
Anyway, I am asking for help, both with my calculations, and also how to complete the task.  I am new to designing electronic circuits but I wont give up!
HELP ME PLEASE!
any advice, designs or calculations will be appreciated.
thankyou very much,
Dougie

Comment: Do you have any specific questions, or should we just do the design work for you?

Comment: Where did you get the value for 340mA? If you have 192 LEDs all lit and the circuit is drawing 340mA that's only 1.7mA per LED

Comment: Hi Plasma, sorry to be cheeky. I appreciate all help available.

Comment: Could you update your question with the LED specs/part numbers. Also I just want to clarify something, when you say "100% power through one colour or 50% power through both colours" do you literally just mean you want the options of Red LED, Cyan LED, both LED?

Comment: Hi Hayman, thanks. so that means (assuming 96 of one colour are lit) 3.4mA is going through it.  and if all are lit but only 50% power, then should it be the same? or is it 1.7mA each still? the value of 340mA is what I was told would be going through it all at 24V.

Comment: part numbers for LEDs are Part No. : LTST-T680VEWT..........and ......LV T6SG-V1BB or 00144424

Comment: So how it works is you would put your current limiting resistor at the top of each branch of 16. This would then limit the current in each branch regardless of how many LEDs are on. However, the more branches you have on the more current you need from your 24Vs. The 340mA you were told is more likely to be the current required by each branch

Comment: Hayman, thanks, I have been asked to create it so that 100% power goes through each colour individually, with some way of switching between red or cyan, and an option of both. yes.  however I have been asked to make it 50% power if both as both would be too powerful.  I can offer to make it simpler by just doing the switching between the 2 colours for now, then try to work on the 'both' option after? Im really trying here but I have little experience in this field.

Comment: What I take from that is your power supply isn't capable of supplying the 4A you would need for all the LEDs. To reduce the power to 50% then you would just need to reduce the current in each branch by 50% by doubling the size of the resistor. I think I've got enough information, I'll post an answer up for you to help

Comment: I have never posted before, and I am glad I did. Thanks :) However, would it be too much to ask for you to show me how to implement the circuit perhaps? you are welcome to say no ;)

Comment: What I'll do is give you a push in the right direction, but I think you'll be able to figure out how to do it

Comment: Ill try, I wont give up, but I may not have a job if I cant do this.. :) thanks x

Answer (score 2):

Probably you could do something like this.

the circuit is not complete. and you will need to do some calculations according to the datasheet to set the correct voltages and currents.

Secondly, as I mentioned before, the max input voltage the TLC IC can take is 7V. hence you may need two regulators (1 for generating the 5V supply voltage for MCU and LEd driver) the other one for generating the supply voltage for the LED string.

check this pic out.

Again I specifically mention this :: THE CIRCUIT IS NOT COMPLETE. YOU WILL HAVE TO WORK OUT A SUITABLE LED ARRAY ACCORDING TO YOUR SPECS. :D

[image]

Comment: As Hayman mentioned, you will have to use some kind of intelligence (aka MCU) to send the data to the LED driver. 
The advantage of MCU is that you have a lot more flexibility compared to other means and you can generate any pattern you want with a few lines of code.

I have seen units that have a lot of LEds on them (especially audio mixers) use a similar architecture like this. 

A slightly crazier solution would be to use an FPGA . thats gna be fun HEHE.

Comment: Cool.

Keep us updated on your progress. :D

Comment: An FPGA would be massively overkill for something of this size. Also you need to take into account the fact that the TLC5917 is going to need to sink about 2.0A with all the LEDs on. You could also do it using a MOSFET and PWM solution but then if you consider the RDS(on) being around 1.5 Ohms that's still 4.5W you need to dissipate. That, or you'd need a MOSFET on every branch which then just becomes expensive.

Comment: Yep. The FPGA is defo an Overkill. Although you could easily combine all the LEd driver logic inside 1 FPGA lol.

with regards to the TLC 5917, I did mention that it would need a good heat sink . If the user matches the LED voltage to the LED string voltage as close as possible, then the power dissipation on the driver will be reduced. this is something that Dougie will have to take into consideration in his final design. 

thirdly, you can get FETs with even lower rds ON values. 

The possiblilites are endless. At the end of the day, its upto him to select the correct topology :D

Comment: Thanks labmat and hayman! rest assured ill keep what you said in my thoughts while designing and assembling and testing this!

Answer (score 2):

You initial calculation is correct. Divide the leds into multiple strings of series leds based on Vs - Vf.

But then you mess up at choosing a resistor. Yes, 16 * 20mA is 320mA. But you don't want a single resistor, with this current level, where one string could dominate the current draw and burn out. Instead, each string should have its own. 1.8V / 20mA = 90 Ohms. Each should have a 90 ohm, or 100 ohm resistor (standard value). And at 1.8V * 20mA = 0.036 Watts, you would use normal 1/4 or even 1/8 Watt resistors (0805 SMD Resistors are 1/8 Watt).

As to switching it on or off, or half on, you could use a mechanical on-off-on switch. The second on side would have a second resistor to half the current. Another 100 ohm in series for each side will take care of halving the current. Since the individual strings have individual resistors, a single resistor can be used for halving. You're combining parallel resistors with series resistors. 0.9V * 160mA = 0.144 Watts. Another 1/4 Watt resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsGHRI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Switch 1 is the On-Off-On. Switch 2 switches between 100% of Red or Cyan. The diagram is example, not an exact schematic. D-Red and D-Cyan are blocking diodes. You may need to play around with the resistor values to make up for their voltage drop. A 50 Ohm resistor instead of 100 Ohm or so.

#### The better option would be a PWM or microcontroller setup. Use a NPN or N-channel mosfet at the low end of the strings to turn on/off/50% or any arbitrary value. Or patterns. At 340mA, a simple 2n2222 NPN would be fine.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffyPym.png)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

these LEDs are mid-power LEDs. I also designed something like this , but with less LEDs (24 LEDs) using a Texas Instrument LED driver (TLC 5917). (Please note that the output voltage of this LED driver is only 20V). If you have a solid 24V supply, then you could use an adjustable voltage regulator to reduce the voltage to 20V. The advantage of using something like this is that

1. simpler solution
2. LED driver can be daisy chained (similar to how you daisy chaining shift registers)
3. Can easily control the LED brightness through an MCU.

I was about to suggest using a Constant current Switching LED driver, but this may be too much for you..

Hope this helps.

(P.S -  the TLC 5917 LED driver has the full design procedure to design something cool ;)

Comment: One more thing.. you will have to make sure that the LED driver is mounted on a proper heat sink because it would have to dissipate quite a bit of heat. Also because its a linear driver, the efficiency will not be as good as a switching driver. :)

Comment: thanks Mat, I would love to see your impeimentation please?

Comment: interesting! still wow though. I wonder how I would be able to modify mine to be like that...? thanks

Comment: There really isn't a reason you posted 3 answers here. They arn't even different. Just edit your initial one.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

check this out. you could just connect another TLC5917 IC to the SDO pin of the 1st IC and repeat for as many LEDs you want.

Comment: for the LED driver, the design procedure is quite straightforward.
Select LEd current
Set LEd Voltage
calculate Power dissipated on LED driver
etc.

The beauty of this circuit is that you can set the LED current using 1 resistor. :D

Comment: The downside unfortunately is that you need a microcontroller

Comment: Yep Hayman is right. You will defo need one.

Comment: If Dougie doesn't want to use an MCU and the TI part, Im sure that Hayman's solution could be recognised by using FETs and a PWM controller like a 555 timer.  where the user could adjust the brightness using a pot for example